# Testnet Fork during Testing Period (Cycles 17-24)

Tags: protocol, testing, amendment

Why is the testnet fork during the Testing Period (Cycles 17-24) only run for 48 hours as compared to the entire duration of 8 cycles of that phase?

Wouldn't it make more sense to test for a longer period of time so that the effects of the upgrade can be observed better on the parallel chain?

Answer (score 1):

The testnet chain is only to validate the ability for the amendment to occur without any initial adverse effects to the network. These protocols should also run in parallel on a dedicated test chain as well, but it's up to the community/proposers to ensure this is setup and well tested.

Testnets should probably run from before the amendments are even proposes in my opinion.

Comment: Note that current amendment voting procedure is already available for testing in the zeronet indeed https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/athens-proposals-injected.html

Comment: I understand that there will be parallel testing happening on a dedicated test chain. But as far as I understand, the testnet fork will have the advantage of forking from an actual context of mainnet, complete with all the accounts and contracts. So I was just wondering that wouldn't it make more sense to have it running for longer than just 48 hours?

Comment: Yeah you could. Would need to submit a protocol amendment to change that.